# Gmail Table space (display:block not working)

Tags: html, gmail, space

I've found many threads about removing the space around images rendering HTML code in Gmail by adding the `style="display:block"` line of code. I've also added a "`float: left`" and line height "`50%`" For some reason my messages are still adding space between table rows.

Are there any other suggestions? I've searched tons of forums.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

A CSS "block" element has whitespace above and below it, and will not allow any other items to be placed on either side of it.

Perhaps you should use `style="display:inline-block"` or `style="display:inline"`. If those aren't working for you, see [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) listing the CSS display types for reference.

Comment: A block element will allow stuff to the sides if it has the 'float' property set to 'right' or 'left'. This can be overcome by setting 'clear' to 'both'.